# What shopping question are (and aren't) welcome on DBA.SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, scope

There are many shopping questions on the site; for example:

- [Tool to generate large datasets of test data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/449/tool-to-generate-large-datasets-of-test-data/541#541)
- [What tools are there for data masking? (MySQL, Linux)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/804/what-tools-are-there-for-data-masking-mysql-linux/9272#9272)
- [Any Open Source / free ETL out there?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2072/2660)
- [Tools to migrate from SQLite to PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2510/2660)
- [Book for Learning RAC](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6795/2660)
- [Are there any good tools for monitoring postgresql databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2770/2660)

The relevant meta.so discussions are:

- [Exceptional cases for list questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112327/exceptional-cases-for-list-questions)
- [Are recommendation questions an acceptable kind of list-type question or should they be closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75521/are-recommendation-questions-acceptable-kinds-of-lists-or-just-plain-lists-that)

The questions we need to answer are:

1. What kind of shopping questions do we welcome here on DBA.SE?
2. What kind of shopping questions are specifically *not* welcome?
3. What should we do about the existing shopping questions (some of which I've referenced above)?

Comment: As Concerned says I don't feel it's been a bring problem and the questions I've seen here are pretty answerable and helpful rather than "should I use VIM or Notepad++?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Black box test: Are the shopping questions causing a problem?

Shopping questions on enterprise or development tools can be quite deep and may require some insignt into the OP's problem to sensibly answer.  For example, getting reliable independent information about B.I. tools such as Cognos or MicroStrategy is not easy to do off the internet.

In some cases the answer to a question is a reference to some feature of a common item that people are often unaware of.  For example, many people do not realise that Visio Pro actually has quite a good database reverse engineering and documentation capability.

I think in the database and development tooling space many of the vendors aren't that well known - for example many people haven't heard of Power Designer, the feature set of Redgate tools or what Embarcadero makes.

- How many people here know about the meta-CASE features of Sparx Enterprise architect or have any idea what you can do with them?
- How many people have any idea just how many different meta-models Powerdesigner actually supports?
- How many people know the limitations of using OLAP cubes as a data source for MicroStrategy or Business Objects?
- How many people know what databases are supported by RapidSQL?

These are all questions that would be of direct interest to posters with needs that are quite common.  However, they would evade most people's google-fu unless you knew the product name or just happened to use exactly the right search terms and picked the product's documentation up by accident.

I think this is a slightly different problem to kiddies wanting to know the best 1337 gaming motherboard or video card.  I'd say that shopping questions relating to specific features of individual products are on-topic.  If the question is obviously inane or incoherent it can be voted down or closed by mods.

Comment: What differentiates a shopping question than exposes a poorly understood topic from one that adds nothing useful? For example, we've closed these shopping questions: [one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10670/2660) and [two](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9706/2660).

Comment: @NickChammas - quite subjective.  Question one really didn't ask anything useful.  The OP did nothing to describe their requirements or why they needed a shared-nothing database.  Question two could have been left open IMO because the OP was describing specific requirements.